# Salesforce Apex Api is Returning response with Escape Character

Tags: apex, httpresponse

Salesforce Apex Api is Returning response with Escape Character in Postman

```
public class ResponseWrapper{
   public string id;
}

ResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper();

responseWrapper.id='asdbkjbf';

return JSON.serialize(responseWrapper);
```

Response in Postman - Although its a valid Json but its not pretty for consumer, how can we fix it ?

```
"{\"id\":\"asdbkjbf\"}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
return JSON.serialize(responseWrapper);
```

Just `return responseWrapper;`

You're returning a String, which Apex is then serializing to JSON by escaping it. You don't need to serialize your API response values. The platform handles this for you.

Comment: But http call can only be made with global and global can not return object, they can only return string @David Reed
```global static string doPost() {}

Comment: It is not accurate that global methods can only return strings.

Comment: @user3444999 you can return any global class, and standard collections like Map.

Comment: Yup Correct you can return any global class - when I changed ResponseWrapper to Global it fixed it. Thanks @DavidReed @sfdcfox
```public class ResponseWrapper{
   public string id;
}```